# Way to switch between users via shortcut/intent/activity?

Tags: multi-user, intents, quick-settings, miui-13

I have a device with MIUI 13, that removed (hid) the Android stock multi-user feature that I need.

I recalled the activity to show the multi-user feature in settings via shortcut maker (adding accounts works normally), but unfortunately, the lock screen UI doesn't show the switch user shortcuts. So, the only way to switch is to enter in multi-user menu and choose one, but with a PIN-protected device, it's not applicable.

Then I need a way to "programmatically" switch to a user with an intent/activity (sorry, I never developed on Android, some concept is not too clear at this time), exactly how to the Android stock lock screen UI does. Having a way to do that in this way, I can place a quick setting tile to achieve my target.

Someone can push me in the right way?

Comment: Hi, just a note that Android app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues. So we can't help with coding, but we probably can help from end-users POV like using 3rd-party apps and/or [tag:automation] apps and providing the commands, etc.

Comment: Sure. This is a borderline thing. The part of app developing is a next step. (and if I can avoid to develop a custom app it's better :) )